# Hinged Connection (pin connection) between two elements (not truss elements) in Anastrut

Tags: python

If I want to use anastruct to analyse two beams that can carry shear and moment internally but should have a pin connection between them, is this possible?

For example:

```ss
ss.add_element(location=[[0,0], [5,0]])
ss.add_element(location=[[5,0], [6,1]], mp={1:0.001})
#*ss.add_element(location=[[6,1], [0,0]])

ss.add_support_fixed(node_id=1)
ss.add_support_fixed(node_id=3)

ss.point_load(node_id=2, Fy=10)

ss.show_structure(scale=0.6)

ss.solve()
ss.show_shear_force()
ss.show_bending_moment()
```

If you run this script, you should see that beams 1 and 2 are both connected to static fixed supports on their far ends and connected to eachother in the middle. At their connection point, I apply a point load. In the moment diagram, we can see that internal moment actually reaches a local maximum at the node between beams 1 and 2 (node 2). I would like to make node 2 a pin/hinge connection between the two beams instead of a rigid one that transmits moment as anastruct seems to assume. To be clear, I don't want to make node 2 a support as I want node 2 to freely translate.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who comes along later, I ended up switching to PyNite. As far as I can tell, it's very similar in what it does to Anastruct, and you have much more control over the nodes between members ("members" in PyNite are similar to "elements" in Anatruct), allowing pin connections and other boundary conditions at these points.